# How to enable dark mode using darkreader package in Vue js website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

How to use DarkMode in Vue js app?

I was trying to import darkmode from [this npm package](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader). However, always got error `DarkMode not defined`.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import `darkreader` like - `import {DarkReader} from 'darkreader'`

Solved the issue by importing as follows

> ````
>     enable as enableDarkMode,
>     disable as disableDarkMode,
>     auto as followSystemColorScheme, } from 'darkreader';   enableDarkMode({
>     brightness: 100,
>     contrast: 90,
>     sepia: 10, });   disableDarkMode();   followSystemColorScheme(); ```
> ````

https://www.npmjs.com/package/darkreader